# TikZ - set of 1-d point charges

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to create a set of alternating (+q,-q etc.) Point charges on a line? Completely new to Tikz.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you after some thing like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
  plus/.pic={
   \node[circle,ball color=orange,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=2.5ex]  {+};
   },
  minus/.pic={
   \node[circle,ball color=green,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=2.5ex]  {-};
   }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x [evaluate={\a=\x+1}] in {0,2,...,16} {
   \pic at (\x,0) {plus};
   \pic at (\a,0) {minus};
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here a MWE using `\foreach` to plot the charges.
You need to set `1` or `-1` for your charges. If you need another height than `1` or `-1` for the charges you can adjust the value to your needs or just use the `yscale`-option of tikz.

Hope this helps.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \y [count=\x from 0] in { %
   1,-1,-1,1,-1 % set of charges
  } {
   \draw (\x,0) -- ++(0,\y);
  }
  \draw [->, >=latex, shorten >= -.5cm, shorten <= -.5cm] (0,0) -- (\x,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

**EDIT:**

For adjusting the spacing between the `x`-values there are two different approaches:

> Using `\foreach` with `evaluate` - You can set `\xdiv` (x-divisor) to adjust the `x`-spacing

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\xdiv}{2}
  \foreach \y [count=\i from 0, evaluate=\i as \x using \i/\xdiv] in { %
   1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1 % set of charges
  } {
   \draw (\x,0) -- ++(0,\y);
  }
  \draw [->, >=latex, shorten >= -.5cm, shorten <= -.5cm] (0,0) -- (\i/\xdiv,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> Using the `xscale`-option (here globally on the whole `tikzpicture` - can also be set with local scopes)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5]
  \foreach \y [count=\x from 0] in { %
   1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1 % set of charges
  } {
   \draw (\x,0) -- ++(0,\y);
  }
    \draw [->, >=latex, shorten >= -.5cm, shorten <= -.5cm] (0,0) -- (\x,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both examples give this images:

[image: rendered image 2]

> To set up nicer looking charges you can use the `arrows`-library of tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \y [count=\x from 0] in { %
   1,-1,-1,1,-1 % set of charges
  } {
   \draw [-o] (\x,0) -- ++(0,\y);
  }
  \draw [->, >=latex, shorten >= -.5cm, shorten <= -.5cm] (0,0) -- (\x,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course you can use other arrow types as stated in the `pgfmanual` section 16.5 (ver. 3.0). For example `[-*]` for a filled dot at the line-end.

[image: rendered image 3]